# How to Combine Generics and Reflection in Golang

Tags: go, generics, reflection

How to make a generic function that would accept a type but not ant instance of defined generic

trying something like

```
func createInstance[T any](valueType reflect.Type) T {
    instance := reflect.New(valueType).Elem().Interface().(T)
    return instance
}

type A struct{}

func main() {
    a := createInstance(A)
    fmt.Println("%v %T", a)
}
```

fails to compile the invocation line with

```
./prog.go:18:25: A (type) is not an expression
```

In other words how to define a `createInstance` func with the notation similar to native `make` one.

And another point how to restrict an argument type to accept only `T` derivatives it self on a compilation level instead of run time check with `valueType.AssignableTo(reflect.TypeOf((T)(nil)).Elem())`. E.g.

```
func createInstance[T BaseType](valueType typeof T) T {
```

Thx.

Comment: What is the actual problem to solve here? Generics are resolved at compile time, and reflection is evaluated at runtime, what you’re showing here doesn't really accomplish anything useful.